# How to make a array inside a json array dynamic using ngFor?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angular, typescript

I am displaying data using json array on my HTML file - I am successful in getting data from the array, but when I am trying to display the data inside the attendance array (using getAttendance.attendance[0].type) I only display the first data from inside the attendance array.

Here is the structure of the array:

[image]

and here is my HTML in displaying the data

```
<div id="attendances" class="list-group-item" style="position: relative;"  *ngFor="let getAttendance of getAttendances">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="user col-sm-12 col-md-2">
                      <div class="user-wrapper">
                      <span class="ellipsis" style="vertical-align: sub;">{{ getAttendance.convertStartTimeRaw | date }}</span>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="timeline col-sm-12 col-md-9">
                      <!-- Display Date -->
                      <div class="progress w-100" *ngIf="getAttendance.attendance.length === 0" style="margin-top: 10px;">
                        <!-- Start -->
                        <div class="progressbar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="100" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" [ngStyle]="{'width': + getAttendance.timedInOverDay + '%'}">
                        </div>
                        <div class="progressbar bg-danger" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="100" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" [ngStyle]="{'width': + getAttendance.durationOverDay + '%'}"></div>
                      </div>

                      <div class="progress w-100" *ngIf="(getAttendance.attendance)?.length > 0 && getAttendance.attendance[0].regularHours >= 9" style="margin-top: 10px;">

                        <!-- With Pre Overtime -->
                        <div class="progressbar preOTregulartime" *ngIf="getAttendance.attendance[0].totalHoursInMins < 0 || getAttendance.attendance[0].totalHoursInMins === 0" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="100" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" [ngStyle]="{'width': + getAttendance.attendance[0].preOvertimeOverDay + '%'}"></div>
                        <!-- Pre Overtime -->
                        <div class="progressbar earlyIn" *ngIf="getAttendance.attendance[0].totalHoursInMins < 0 || getAttendance.attendance[0].totalHoursInMins === 0" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="100" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" [ngStyle]="{'width': + getAttendance.attendance[0].absoluteTotalHoursInMins + '%', 'background-color': getAttendance.attendance[0].type == 'ot' ? '#9744BE' : '#607D8B'}"></div>

                        <!-- Regular Hours With Pre Overtime -->
                        <div class="progressbar bg-success regulartime" *ngIf="getAttendance.attendance[0].totalHoursInMins < 0 || getAttendance.attendance[0].totalHoursInMins === 0" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="100" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" [ngStyle]="{'width': + getAttendance.attendance[0].timeInOverEndTime + '%'}"></div>
                        <!-- With Pre Overtime: END -->

                        <!-- Regular Hours With Pre Overtime -->
                        <div class="progressbar LateOut" *ngIf="getAttendance.attendance[0].totalHoursInMins < 0 || getAttendance.attendance[0].totalHoursInMins === 0" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="100" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" [ngStyle]="{'width': + getAttendance.attendance[0].endTimeOverTimeOut + '%', 'background-color': getAttendance.attendance[0].type == 'ot' ? '#9744BE' : '#607D8B'}"></div>
                        <!-- With Pre Overtime: END -->



                        <!-- Start Duration of Day -->
                        <!-- <div class="progressbar" role="progressbar" *ngIf="getAttendance.attendance[0].regularHours > 0 && getAttendance.attendance[0].totalHoursInMins > 0" aria-valuenow="100" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" [ngStyle]="{'width': + getAttendance.timedInOverDay + '%'}">
                        </div> -->
                        <!-- Time In Regular Hours -->
                        <!-- <div class="progressbar bg-success" *ngIf="getAttendance.attendance[0].regularHours > 0 && getAttendance.attendance[0].totalHoursInMins > 0" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="100" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" [ngStyle]="{'width': + getAttendance.attendance[0].overtime + '%'}"></div> -->

                        <!-- Undertime -->
                        <!-- <div class="progressbar bg-danger undertime" *ngIf="getAttendance.attendance[1] && getAttendance.attendance[1].undertimeInMins && getAttendance.durationOverDay != '0'" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="100" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" [ngStyle]="{'width': + getAttendance.attendance[1].undertime + '%'}"></div> -->

                        <!-- Overtime -->
                        <!-- <div class="progressbar bg-purple overtime" *ngIf="getAttendance.attendance[0].totalHoursInMins > 0 && getAttendance.durationOverDay != '0' && getAttendance.attendance[0].totalHoursInMins > 0" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="100" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" [ngStyle]="{'width': + getAttendance.attendance[0].overtime + '%'}"></div> -->

                      </div>

                      <div class="progress w-100" *ngIf="(getAttendance.attendance)?.length > 0 && getAttendance.attendance[0].regularHours < 9" style="margin-top: 10px;">

                        <div class="progressbar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="100" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" [ngStyle]="{'width': + getAttendance.timedInOverDay + '%'}">
                        </div>

                        <div class="progressbar bg-danger" *ngIf="getAttendance.attendance[0].halfday < 0" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="100" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" [ngStyle]="{'width': + getAttendance.attendance[0].exception + '%'}">
                        </div>

                        <div class="progressbar bg-success" *ngIf="getAttendance.attendance[0].halfday < 0 && getAttendance.attendance[0].undertime < 0" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="100" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" [ngStyle]="{'width': + getAttendance.attendance[0].overtime + '%'}">
                        </div>

                        <!-- Regular Hours With Pre Overtime -->
                        <div class="progressbar bg-success regulartime" *ngIf="getAttendance.attendance[0].undertime >= 0" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="100" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" [ngStyle]="{'width': + getAttendance.attendance[0].timeInOverEndTime + '%'}"></div>
                        <!-- With Pre Overtime: END -->

                        <!-- Regular Hours With Pre Overtime -->
                        <div class="progressbar LateOut" *ngIf="getAttendance.attendance[0].undertime >= 0" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="100" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" [ngStyle]="{'width': + getAttendance.attendance[0].endTimeOverTimeOut + '%', 'background-color': getAttendance.attendance[0].type == 'ot' ? '#9744BE' : '#607D8B' }"></div>
                        <!-- With Pre Overtime: END -->

                        <div class="progressbar bg-danger" *ngIf="getAttendance.attendance[0].undertime < 0" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="100" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" [ngStyle]="{'width': + getAttendance.attendance[0].absoluteUndertime + '%'}">
                        </div>
                      </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="total col-sm-12 col-md-1">
                      <div class="total-wrapper font-weight-bold" style="margin-top: 9px; text-align: center">{{ getAttendance.attendance[0] ? getAttendance.attendance[0].regularHours : '0' }} Hrs</div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
```

I am struggling on how to condition that if the attendance array has a type of "ot" the background-color is "#9744BE" otherwise "#607D8B"

or how can I dynamically display or get data inside the attendance array.

thanks in advance!

Comment: If its just matter of css (Set background), you dont need to iterate entire child collection again. Instead you can use find/findIndex on array and check that your desired condition satisfy or not and do logic accordingly. https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_findindex.asp

Comment: before I set the background I first need to know if the data inside the attendance array has a type of "ot".

Comment: Check this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/harshadray/arw86gmd/3/  It will provide you code which tells that array have value or not. If output > 0, you can say element exist else not.

Comment: Thanks bro! This is a new learning for me. Will definitely try this method

Comment: This method worked! i can now easily determine the specific array dynamically! Thanks! exactly what I needed. +1

Comment: Posted workaround as answer, if you can accept and upvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If its just matter of css (Set background), you don't need to iterate entire child collection again. Instead you can use find/findIndex on array and check that your desired condition satisfy or not and do logic accordingly.

Check this fiddle: [jsfiddle.net/harshadray/arw86gmd/3](https://jsfiddle.net/harshadray/arw86gmd/3)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <body>

    <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
    <p id="demo"></p>

    <script>
      var ages = [{
        x: 1
      }, {
        x: 2
      }, {
        x: 3
      }, {
        x: 4
      }];

      function checkAdult(age) {
        return age.x == 3; // condition
      }

      function myFunction() {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = ages.findIndex(checkAdult);
      }

    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

If output > 0, you can say element exist else not.

Answer (score 3):

you can use *ngFor again. So instead of `getAttendance.attendance[0]` use `*ngFor="let attendance of getAttendance.attendance"` and then access it with `attendance.type`

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But can you tell me where should I use the second ngFor on my HTML?

Comment: In this line would be best `<div class="progress w-100" *ngIf="(getAttendance.attendance)?.length > 0 && getAttendance.attendance[0].regularHours >= 9" style="margin-top: 10px;">` as i see it all calls to getAttendance.attendance[0] are in children of this div